# Attach function to element, $.fn.test vs $.bind('test', funct... vs $.data('test', funct

Tags: jquery

If you want to attach a function to an element in jQuery you can basically do either below three ways. What are the pros, cons of each?

<s>1)</s>

```
var a = $('a')
a.fn.testFunc = function () {...};
$(a).testFunc();
```

*This one was wrong, please ignore; see #4 below*

2)

```
$('a').bind('testFunc',function() {...});
$('a').trigger('testFunc');
```

3)

```
$('a').data('testFunc', function(){...});
$('a').data('testFunc')();
```

4) *(added to replace #1)*

```
$.fn.testFunc = function () {...};
$(a).testFunc();
```

Comment: first one isn't valid

Comment: Editing the question in a way that invalidates posted answers isn't how it's done on SO. I've adjusted your edit accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find line through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>#1 won't work at all, there is no `fn` property on jQuery *instances*. There is an `fn` property on the `jQuery` (`$`) function itself, which refers to the prototype **all** jQuery instances inherit.</s>

#2 is more properly called a custom event. It's overkill for just attaching a function. It's useful if you may need the features of the event subsystem, though.

#3 is straightforward, is element-specific, and takes advantage of jQuery's data caching handling and disposal.

#4 adds the function to the jQuery prototype, which means it will be available on **all** jQuery instances, not just that one, which is probably overkill.

Just to round out your options, you also have (call it #5):

```
$("a")[0].testFunc = function(){ /*...*/};
$("a")[0].testFunc();
```

That *directly* attaches the function to the element, as an expando property. I wouldn't recommend it over using `data`; `data` uses jQuery's expando, which minimizes the possibility of conflict.

Of those five options, #3 seems your best bet ***if*** you really do need to attach a function to a DOM element.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer